# When do we use was/were with "headed", and when can it be omitted?

Tags: grammar, verbs, past-tense

For instance, in a sentence such as this:

> Joe Biden headed for the White House on Monday for a meeting with Kamala Harris.

What would the correct form be — Joe Biden **was headed** or **Joe Biden headed**?

Answer (score 0):

> Joe Biden headed towards the White House...

This is the past tense.  You use it to describe an action that occurred in the past.

> Joe Biden is headed towards the White House

This is the passive voice in the present tense.  It means the same as

*Someone heads Joe Biden towards the White House*

> Joe Biden was headed towards the White House

This is the passive voice in the past tense. It means

*Someone headed Joe Biden towards the White House.*

Note, the passive voice forms mean that someone did it to Joe Biden,

Comment: a misspelling, fixed.

Answer (score -2):

- Joe Biden [is] headed for the White House on Monday for a meeting with Kamala Harris. (*correct form*)

This is journalistic style; it allows for the omission of the help verb in titles.

> ([MacMillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/be-heading-headed-for-something)) be heading​/​headed for somethingbe heading​/​headed for something
>
> if you are heading or headed for something, it is likely to happen to you soon
>
> • It appears that the rebels are heading for victory.

As a title in a newspaper  this sentence means  that Joe Biden will go to the White House on the coming Monday so as to  meet with Kamala Harris (on that same day).

Comment: I don't see any indication in the question that this is a headline.

Comment: @stangdon There isn't any explicit indication, true; but you can't omit the help verb in any  other  case either.

Comment: There is no help verb to omit. As James says in another answer _headed_ is simple past, not pp.